# Fetch cursor from multiple tables view PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, cursor, plpgsql

I try until couple of hours to fetch all the row from a view, created from multiple tables.

I have two tables (Position, and Vector) to which correspond respectively two custom composite types , **type_position** and **type_vector**

**Position** (id, sys_time, lat, lon)

**Vector**   (id, sys_time, speed)

I want to create a temporary VIEW in plpgsql procedure to bring together all Position and Vector and order them by sys_time so i wrote :

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW posAndVectView AS
                    SELECT * from position
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT * from vector;
```

I need to iterate over this view and made some work depends on Position and Vector attributes.

So i think i should use a cursor :

```
DECLARE 
 manyRows refcursor;
BEGIN

OPEN manyRows FOR 
SELECT * FROM posAndVectView ORDER BY sys_time ASC;
LOOP
FETCH manyRows INTO posOrVect;
EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
...
END LOOP;
CLOSE manyRows;
```

**So my question is what should the type of the posOrVect variable be in the DECLARE section ?**

It seems to be sometimes a type_vector, sometimes a type_position...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer it is pretty simple.
I need to declare the posOrVect variable with the **record** type as its mentionned in the PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-declarations.html) :

> Record variables are similar to row-type variables, but they have no
>   predefined structure. They take on the actual row structure of the row
>   they are assigned during a SELECT or FOR command. The substructure of
>   a record variable can change each time it is assigned to. A
>   consequence of this is that until a record variable is first assigned
>   to, it has no substructure, and any attempt to access a field in it
>   will draw a run-time error.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. The type should be `posAndVectView`.

Like for any other table, there is also a composite type with the same name as a temporary table.

But do you need a view? You could just open the cursor for the query with the `UNION`. In that case, you'd use type `position` because it is the first table.

Comment: I created the view in the body of the procedure so if you are right it means that the type corresponding to my view is known in the DECLARE section before my view is actually created in the BEGIN section? I'll test that.

Comment: I try to use posAndVectView and posAndVectView%ROWTYPE to declaring posOrVect variable in DECLARE section but as i expected i've got an error because the view is not already created so the posAndVectView type is unknown.

Comment: You are right. I missed that you create the temporary view inside the function itself. Using `record` is a good solution. But as I mentioned, I don't think you really need a view for this.